# wp_insert_user keeps echoing values

Tags: plugin-development

This is bugging the heck out of me. Essentially I've narrowed the issue down to one line of code:

```
$user_id = wp_insert_user ($userdata);
```

From what I can tell nothing should be echoed here, but I should get the user_id returned from the wp_insert_user function. What I'm getting though is the email and other values echoed back.

I will paste the code for the entire function at the moment, but I've tested it apart and this is the line of code causing the echo in my ajax call, messing up my return because its not formatted in my JSON variable. See code below (**Thanks you in advance for any help I can get with this, really need it at this point**)

```
public function registerUser(){
        $event = $_REQUEST['event'];
        $nonce=$_REQUEST['ajax_nonce'];
        if (! wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'ajax_nonce') ) {
            $response = json_encode( 
                array( 
                    'success' => false,
                    'html' => 'Please stop trying break me. For security reasons your IP has been logged'
                ) 
            );
            header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
            echo $response;
            die();
        }
        global $wpdb;
        $html = ""; 
        //We shall SQL escape all inputs  
        $user_login = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['username']);  
        if(empty($user_login)) {  
            $error = 1;
            $html .= "<li>Username could not be created because you have not completed your first and last name.</li>";  
        }
        $user_email = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['email']);  
        if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/", $user_email)) {
            $error = 1;  
            $html .= "<li>Please enter a valid email.</li>";  
        }
        $user_pass = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['password']);
        $confirm_password = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['confirm_password']);
        if(empty($user_pass) || $user_pass != $confirm_password){
            $error = 1;  
            $html .= "<li>Passwords do not match.</li>";
        }
        if(empty($error)){
            $first_name = $_REQUEST['first'];
            $last_name = $_REQUEST['last'];
            $display_name = $_REQUEST['first']." ".$_REQUEST['last'];
            $userdata = compact('user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'display_name');
            $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
            if ( is_wp_error($user_id) ){
                print_r($status);
                $error = 1;
                $html = "<b>Username already exists</b>. Please try another one or <a href='".get_bloginfo('url')."/contact'>contact us</a>";  
            } else {
                update_usermeta( $user_id, 'phone', $_POST['phone'] );  
                $from = get_option('admin_email');  
                $headers = 'From: '.$from . "\r\n";  
                $subject = "Painter Registration Successful!";  
                $msg = "<h2>Registration successful!</h2><h3>Your login details:</h3><br/><b>Username</b>: $username<br/><b>Password</b>: $password<br/><br/>Thank you again for joining Brush Party, now you can login and finish signing up for the <a href='".get_bloginfo('url')."/registration/?event=$event'>next party here!</a>";
                $html = "Awesome! You are officially a registered painter at Brush Party. That was easy, and you thought painting was going to be hard... Now you just need to check your email for you login details";  
            }  
        }
        $response = json_encode( 
            array( 
                'success' => $status = (empty($error)) ? true : false,
                'first' => $_REQUEST['first'],
                'last' => $_REQUEST['last'],
                'phone' => $_REQUEST['phone'],
                'email' => $_REQUEST['email'],
                'html' => $html
            ) 
        );
        add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html";'));
        wp_mail( $email, $subject, $msg, $headers );  
        // response output
        header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
        echo $response;
        die(); // WP AJAX calls must die
    }
```

EDIT:

I've since looked at the user.php file and targeted the issue at line 1371, here's the code there

```
if ( $update )
        do_action('profile_update', $user_id, $old_user_data);
    else
        do_action('user_register', $user_id);
```

Comment: If this were happening to me, I'd suspect a spurious debugging `var_dump` somewhere :) Maybe in a filter or action.

Comment: Ok so I edited the question, but still not sure how I would find out where a var_dumb like that would be happening. I'm at a complete loss and this is breaking my JSON response so I need to figure it out soon.

My ajax returns 200 with this response:
**email value** _{success:true, field:value, ...}_

Comment: How are you invoking the function registerUser ?

Comment: Sorry this question is outdated, I decided on a different route  to accomplish what I needed. I believe at the time I was invoking the function through an ajax call with hooks like so:

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_registerUser', array( $this, 'registerUser' ) ); 
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_registerUser', array( $this, 'registerUser' ) );`

Answer (score 1):

If you really narrowed it to  line 1371 then you probably have a plugin hooking on those hooks and outputing that message, might even be your own code as it looks like  somthing that supposed to be sent as a response to AJAX request. Just search for user_register and profile_update in your code and in the other active plugins.

Comment: I only have a few plugins installed, and none that should include that function. Turned them off, couldn't turn off my plugin because that's where this code is, but searched through it and as expected no dice. I did find a function in my functions.php prior to posting here and I took that out and still experienced issues. :(

Comment: since it is probably done on development server can you comment out those lines in core just to make sure this is where the message is originated? If it is you will need to find the place in the code that hooks to those hooks.

Comment: So I commented those out and everything worked perfectly, but I can't do that (edit the WP Core like that). So not sure how I'm ever going to find out where there is a hook for it, I've searched everywhere and I built this theme and the plugin from scratch, didn't even know this function existed until this week.

Comment: So I was able to use a tool found here: [link](http://www.rarst.net/script/debug-wordpress-hooks/)
With that I was able to do a identify all hook calls and as expected this is all I see.
>>>>> user_register
10 (object) PodioAPI -> podio_registration (1) 
 (object) acf_everything_fields -> save_user (1)

Comment: **UPDATE:** Used the tool to post the hooks as they are called and with that my JSON response came back with those same hooks as well as this one: **WP_Internal_Pointers::dismiss_pointers_for_new_users** But I have no idea what that is.

Comment: If this is a paid work on someone elses site maybe it is time to stop development and redefine the scope of the work, as it seems like the podia integration is doing some things which are overlapping with your functionality. At the minimum you need to understand why and when podio uses those hooks.

Comment: This is for a personal project of mine, and because I have plans to integrate Podio into a wordpress plugin. Podio has nothing to do with this, at this part of the plugin podio's API isn't even involved I'm just simply making a custom registration form that THEN will have Podio functionality. The reason PodioAPI showed up in the hook is because that's where my hook was placed (see original question)